# unable to view data from downloaded file using PHP

Tags: php, download, xampp

I have written code for downloading a file. with this code I am downloading the file, but when I open the file I cant see any data. Below is the code I am using.

```
<?php
$namekey = $_REQUEST['key'];

$tmp = explode(".",$file['namekey']);
switch ($tmp[count($tmp)-1]) {
  case "pdf": $ctype="application/pdf"; break;
  case "exe": $ctype="application/octet-stream"; break;
  case "zip": $ctype="application/zip"; break;
  case "docx":
  case "doc": $ctype="application/msword"; break;
  case "csv":
  case "xls":
  case "xlsx": $ctype="application/vnd.ms-excel"; break;
  case "ppt": $ctype="application/vnd.ms-powerpoint"; break;
  case "gif": $ctype="image/gif"; break;
  case "png": $ctype="image/png"; break;
  case "jpeg":
  case "jpg": $ctype="image/jpg"; break;
  case "tif":
  case "tiff": $ctype="image/tiff"; break;
  case "psd": $ctype="image/psd"; break;
  case "bmp": $ctype="image/bmp"; break;
  case "ico": $ctype="image/vnd.microsoft.icon"; break;
  default: $ctype="application/force-download";
}
$location="uploads/sop/".$namekey."";
$fszie=filesize($location);
header("Pragma: public"); // required
header("Expires: 0");
header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
header("Cache-Control: private",false); // required for certain browsers
header("Content-Type: $ctype");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"".$namekey."\";" );
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
header("Content-Length: ".$fsize);
ob_clean();
flush();
//readfile( 'uploads/sop/'.$file['namekey'] );
readfile( $location);

?>
```

is there any mistake in the code.Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure exactly what's the reason.... But, after removing the below code its working good...

```
header("Content-Length: ".$fsize);
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Check out the first two lines of code:

```
<?php
$namekey = $_REQUEST['key'];

$tmp = explode(".",$file['namekey']);
```

Here $file['namekey'] would be undefined, you should use $namekey:

```
<?php
$namekey = $_REQUEST['key'];

$tmp = explode(".",$namekey);
```

Comment: Well you can comment out the headers: Content-Type, Content-Disposition, Content-Transfer-Encoding and Content-Length and try like that so that you can see any errors generated

Comment: tried all the permutation and combinations with header... still the data is not visible....